# Handle Async alert popup in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, alert, protractor

I have a async call on blur of textbox. On success of async call it makes an alert:

```
var obj = {
    "header.a_currency_name" : "Dollar",
    "header.a_currency_code" : "USD",
    "header.a_currency_symbol" : "$"
}

for(var key in  obj) {
    element(by.model(key)).clear();
    element(by.model(key)).sendKeys(obj[key]);
}
```

In the iteration of 'for' loop When it set `header.a_currency_name` the value `Dollar` & go for next model it makes an alert.

What I want is click "OK" to alert box & go for setting next model (i.e. textbox).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a javascript alert, you can *switch to it and accept*:

```
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

You may also need to [wait for the alert to be present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.alertIsPresent):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000);
```